# how to point this script to one folder for reading and another for writing

Tags: perl, directory

I can't seem to get this script to open from one directory and write to another.  Both Directories exist.  I've commented out what I tried.  Funny this is it runs fine when I place it in the directory with the files to process.  Here's the code:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings "all";
 my $tmp;
 my $dir = ".";
 #my $dir = "Ask/Parsed/Html4/";
 opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Cannot open directory: $dir!\n";
 my @files = readdir(DIR);
 closedir(DIR);
 open my $out, ">>output.txt" or die "Cannot open output.txt!\n";
 #open my $out, ">>Ask/Parsed/Html5/output.txt" or die "Cannot open output.txt!\n";
 foreach my $file (@files)
 {
 if($file =~ /html$/)
 {
    open my $in, "<$file" or die "Cannot open $file!\n";
    undef $tmp;
    while(<$in>)
    {
        $tmp .= $_;
    }
    print $out ">$file\n";
    print $out "$tmp\n";
    #print $out "===============";
    close $in;
  }
  }
  close $out;
```

Answer (score 2):

The directories you use -- `.` and `Ask/Parsed/Html4/` -- are *relative* paths, which means they are relative to your current working directory, and so it makes a difference where in the file system you are currently located when you run the script.

In addition, the files you are opening -- `output.txt` and `$file` -- have no path information, so Perl will look in your current working directory to find them.

There are a few ways to solve this.

- You could `cd` to the directory where your files are before running the script, and open the directory as `.` as you currently do
- You could achieve the same effect by calling `chdir` from within the script, which will change the current working directory and make the program ignore your location when you ran it
- Or you could add an *absolute* directory path to the beginning of the file names, preferably using `catfile` from `File::Spec::Functions`

However I would choose to use `glob` -- which works in the same way as command-line *filename expansion* -- in preference to `opendir` / `readdir` as the resulting strings include the path (if one was specified in the parameter) and there is no need to separately filter the `.html` files.

I would also choose to undefine the *input record separator* `$/` to read the whole file, rather than reading it line-by-line and concatenating them all.

Finally, if you are running version 10 or later of Perl 5 then it is simpler to `use autodie` rather than checking the success of every `open`, `readline`, `close`, `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir` etc.

Something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my $dir = '/path/to/Ask/Parsed/Html4';

my @html = glob "$dir/*.html";

open my $out, '>>', "$dir/output.txt";

for my $file (@html) {

  my $contents = do {
    open my $in, '<', $file;
    local $/;
    <$in>;
  };

  print $out "> $file\n";
  print $out "$contents\n";
  print $out "===============";
}

close $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely trying to access the files from where ever you are calling this from. If you're files are located relative to the location of the script use the following example to provide a full path;

```
use FindBin; 
my $file = "$FindBin::Bin/Ask/Parsed/Html5/output.txt";
```

If your file us not relative to the script, provide the full path;

```
my $file = "/home/john.doe/Ask/Parsed/Html5/output.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that readdir() only returns the file name. If you want to open it prepend the directory

eg

open my $in, "<", "$dir/$file" or die "Cannot open $file!\n";

Note that best practice says you should be using the three parameter version of open, otherwise